# Convertir sitio webforms en Proyecto Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, webforms, iis

Tengo una sitio webforms creado con Visual Studio 2015 en C#, publicado en el servidor local Microsoft IIS del PC y tengo el archivo .sln que me permite abrirlo. Quiero traspasarlo a otro PC con Win10 pero lo quiero convertir en un Proyecto de Visual Studio, es decir, sin tener que estar publicado en un IIS
Se puede hacer? alguien sabe cómo?

Gracias

Comment: Depende del framework que hayas usado los posibles problemas lo mas recomendable es que crees una nueva solucion con un nuevo proyecto webforms y entonces copies y pegues todos tus existentes webforms en el nuevo proyecto, cuida que tengan la misma version de framework los proyectos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tienes el .sln de VS2015 puedes abrirlo "sin problemas". ¿Lo has intentado? Porque abrir seguramente lo abrirá, y en algunas cosas intentara un upgrade si es necesario al framework mas reciente (si no tienes instalado el sdk correspondiente)

Pero igualmente lo mejor seria:

- PASO 1. Abrir con la version mas reciente de VS2019
- PASO 2. Ver si tienes instalado dicho framework (no aclaras, pero puede ser NET 2.0, 3.5 etc.) y ver si tienes todos los componentes necesarios (o tendras que referenciarlos de ultima a los archivos fisicos de .dll)
- PASO 3: Si todo compila bien y funciona (bien!)

Si no en el Paso 2, te solicitara un upgrade! Si esto funciona ok

Sino es una alternativa o incluso tambien un PASO 4: Crear una solución nueva de Webforms e ir pasando artefacto (clase, webform, etc) del proyecto anterior

Mas info

- [Referencia de migración y actualización de proyectos para Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/porting/port-migrate-and-upgrade-visual-studio-projects?view=vs-2019)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía.